# virtualenv Failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, centos7, virtualenv

When SELinx is in `permissive` the Django webapp runs fine with no alerts. The below error appears in the Apache error log, once SELinux is set to enforcing, but no alerts are logged to `audit.log`.

```
[wsgi:error]     import psycopg2 as Database
[wsgi:error]   File "/mnt/data/venv/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
[wsgi:error] ImportError: /venv/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

The system is running CentOS 7, Apache httpd 2.4 2.4.6 (rpm installed), Python 3.4.2 (source installed), and pip installed: mod_wsgi 4.4.5, virtualenv 12.0.5, psycopg2 2.5.4, and Django 1.7.2.

Nothing is logged by Django.

The current file context type of the virtualenv directory is `httpd_sys_content_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`httpd_sys_script_exec_t` seems to be the best file context type to be used, and only needs to be applied to the shared object file involved.

```
<virtualenv/path/>lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so‌​.
```

As root or super user:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t </full-path-to-file/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so‌>
restorecon -v </full-path-to-file/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so‌>
```

The context change will persist through reboot and filesystem relabeling.

*[Based off of this miss-located question on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919771/centos-6-4-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-permission-denied)*

Comment: ***In case if the thing dont go as expected, then to revert back file to original form as before, use:***
```semanage fcontext --delete -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t </full-path-to-file/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so‌>``` ; 
```restorecon -v </full-path-to-file/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so‌>```

***same way for adding and deleting a port, use:***
```sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8585``` ; 
```sudo semanage port --delete -t http_port_t -p tcp 8585```